# Why Laravel-Echo doesn't work on my stage server?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, broadcasting

It's just not working and doesn't show any errors.
Frontend side:

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import axios from 'axios';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Pusher.logToConsole = true;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
});

Pusher.logToConsole = true;
window.Echo.private('report-generated')
    .listen('ReportGenerated', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        handleResponse(e.data);
    });
```

In the backend side I create new channel in the Event:

```php
class ReportGenerated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        dd($this->data);
        return new PrivateChannel('report-generated');
    }
}
```

Queues works by redis and works properly, if launch a code above we see in the console:

```
[2021-11-08 10:37:47][b2SKHMqqO3l2g2UN4G0bjp3bE3YGfjG3] Processing: App\Jobs\GenerateReport
[2021-11-08 10:37:47][b2SKHMqqO3l2g2UN4G0bjp3bE3YGfjG3] Processed:  App\Jobs\GenerateReport
[2021-11-08 10:37:47][PdAhlQqLvEEdUtb5MfBhFy4VAyEONz9a] Processing: App\Events\ReportGenerated
array:2 [
  "status" => "success"
  "file" => "transactions-1636367867.pdf"
]
```

Of course I've tested without `dd()`.
Seems that everything fine, but in the browser console nothing happens by this event, only these logs:

```
Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]
pusher.js?782e:1206 Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-ap2.pusher.com:443/app/ea46c356a251f1d332eb?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false"}]
pusher.js?782e:1206 Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected with new socket ID 9001.16292364"]
pusher.js?782e:1206 Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"","channel":"report-generated"}}]
pusher.js?782e:1206 Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"report-generated","data":{}}]
pusher.js?782e:1206 Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on report-generated for pusher:subscription_succeeded"]
```

BUT ON THE LOCAL ENVIRONMENT EVERYTHING WORKS FINE! It's problem only on the stage server. I don't understand the reason of this...

Yes, I changed driver `BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher`, done vendor:publish, uncommented Broadcast string in the config/app.php, permanently cleaned cache by commands: optimize, cache:clear, writed npm run dev to update js-scripts.
I even updated pusher credentials in env file for stage server cause in the local I used other credentials. (pusher app id etc..).

To sum up - queues works, event dispatches, channel creates but laravel Echo don't see anything...
Can someone tell me what step I missed?

Comment: Do you see the event show in the Pusher debug console (available in the Pusher Dashboard)? This will help determine if the event is making it as far as the Pusher service, or if the issue lies between the service and the client.

Comment: @doydoy, yes, pusher dashboard says there were connects: ```Peak connections today 2; Total messages sent today 8``` and also says "no data"